# jQuery scroll only detecting scroll at very top of the page and bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-scrollable

I'm currently trying to change the colour of a div when the scroll is at a certain vertical value. Though at the moment my scroll doesn't seem to be detecting anything in between the top or bottom of the page.

So when I hit the bottom of the page I see 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc and when I hit the top it appears 0, -1, -2, -3, etc. So it seems that there is no page in between the top and the bottom of the page as scroll isn't triggered anywhere other than the very top or bottom of the page.

HTML structure:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">  
         <div id="post-view">
             <div id="cover-image">
                 <header>
                     <div class="title">
                     </div>
                     <div class="sub-title">
                     </div>
                 </header>                 
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="suggested">
             content in here
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(y);
});
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: #ffffff !important;
overflow-x: hidden;
margin:0;
}

header{
width:100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
background: #333333;
overflow:hidden;
padding:10px 0 0 0 ;
}

#container{
width:100%;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, if you need any more info just comment. Thanks!

Comment: It is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/wbMdZ/

Comment: That's really weird, as it's just not happening for me regardless what I try.

Comment: @Lorenzo I added some CSS styling which I have, is there anything you can see which could potentially trigger this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see above I have in my CSS `html, body { height:100% }` this was the culprit. Really strange. Got it working now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: same problem here, can confirm this definitely fixed it for me, this exact problem, very strange!

Comment: @ToniLeigh Good stuff - glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Made an element 2k px high to know that it would scroll.
The h2 tells you how far its scrolled. Works?

http://cdpn.io/oHACi

Comment: It doesn't work at all, this code just gives me the same output. Could it be the layout of my id's and classes which are affecting what is being scrolled?

Comment: I added some CSS styling which I have, is there anything you can see which could potentially trigger this problem?

Comment: Perhaps your content is not taller than ur window? I updated the codepen http://codepen.io/erikpantzar/pen/oHACi